# Missing character 1 in font bbold11

Tags: fonts, math-mode, miktex

I have a problem with my (freshly updated) MiKTeX installation: I like to use `\mathbbold{1}` from the `bbold` package to obtain a blackboard bold 1. This works with TeX Live under Linux, but for font size 11 it does not work with MiKTeX. If I compile

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}
\newcommand{\ind}{\mathbbold{1}}
\begin{document}
$a$ \tracingall $\mathbbold{1}$
\end{document}
```

then in the log file I get the line

```
Missing character: There is no 1 in font bbold11!
```

and no blackboard bold 1 in the output. With TeX Live (and with font size 10) everything works as expected.

The problem seems to be that under TeX Live, `bbold/Ubbold.fd` is loaded, whereas under MiKTeX, `jknappen\ubbold.fd` is loaded. The former uses `bbold10.tfm`, the latter `bbold11.tfm`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have the latest updates in MiKTeX, but everything works fine...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Strange ... I just even tried removing the `MiKTeX` folder in `AppData\Local`, but the error persists.

Comment: I get `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX/tex/latex/bbold/ubbold.fd` loaded. Also I don't have `bbold11.tfm` but only `C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/tfm/public/bbold/bbold10.tfm`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot for you help so far. I made a funny test: `\IfFileExists{ubbold.fd}{\show\relax}{\show\bye}`. Under MiKTeX, this shows `\relax`, und TeX Live it tries to show `\bye` although the file `ubbold.fd` exists!!

Comment: I confirm that with latest miktex, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't count it as a miktex bug if two packages uses the same file name and imho the package maintainer should sort this out and not the tex distribuations.

When such name clashes in the same branch of a texmf tree exists the search result is not predictable -- it can e.g. depend on the installation order, date or whatever.

So you have imho the following possibilities:

- Move the correct fd-file to tex\latex in a root which is searched first (e.g. your local texmf).
- Copy the font definitions directly to your document. Then no fd-file will be loaded:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}
  \DeclareFontEncoding{U}{}{}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> gen * bbold
     <10> <10.95> bbold10
    <12> <14.4> bbold12
   <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> bbold17
    }{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

  \begin{document}
  $\mathbbold{1}$
  \end{document}
  ```
- Make a copy of the correct fd-file e.g. as `Umybbold.fd` and store it somewhere where it can be found and then call declare the font as

  ```
  \DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{mybbold}{m}{n}
  ```

Comment: I like option 2 - thanks! But I'm still rather puzzled: Is this really a name clash? One file is `Ubbold.fd`, the other is `ubbold.fd`. Ah, maybe I understand now: Under Windows this is a name clash, under Linux it isn't. Correct?

Comment: Yes, windows doesn't care about cases in file names.

Answer (score 4):

In [revision 4975](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=4975) of TeX Live (2007-09-18) we find the annotation

> omit ubbold.fd from jknapltx, clash with Ubbold.fd + sauter bbold disfunctional? (Zdenek Wagner, 9 Aug 2007 16:20:21 +0200)

So my suggestion is to remove the file `ubbold.fd` from your system and file a bug report to MiKTeX's maintainer.

Comment: Link: [MiKTeX Bugs](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/).

Comment: I did remove (or rather, rename) `ubbold.fd`, but then the system didn't find `Ubbold.fd` ... at the moment I use the unsatisfactory solution of an additional copy of `Ubbold.fd` in my working directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Rebuild the font name database.

Comment: @egreg: Do you mean "Refresh FNDB"? This is did. Otherwise, can you tell me how to rebuild the font name database?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Sorry, but I can't say more than that.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: “Refresh FNDB” _and_ “Update Formats”. Or on command line: `initexmf --update-fndb´ followed by `initexmf --mkmaps`, as admin add for both the switch `--admin`.